# In a Discussion Involving Formal Languages, Can a Word Be Regarded as an "Expression"?

Tags: terminology, formal-languages, article-writing

In order to avoid sounding repetitious by too frequently using the word "word," I would like to be able use the word "expression," writing, *e.g.*, "Applying the function $f$ to the lang$_{1}$ word $ab$ yields the expression $abba$, which is a word in the lang$_{2}$ language."

Is that an acceptable usage of the term *expression*?

Also, if I were to instead write "Applying the function $f$ to the lang$_{1}$ word $ab$ yields the word $abba$, which is a member of the lang$_2$ language," could I be criticized for first identifying $abba$ as a word without specifying the set in which it is considered such until I reach my sentence's dependent clause to reveal that crucial piece of information?  Or is it okay to call something a "word" in the general sense that there exists some language in which it is a word?  (I know I could rephrase using "...the lang$_{2}$ word $abba$...", but such rephrasing would prove extremely awkward, given the context of my discussion.)

Comment: I think your second sentence is fine.

Answer (score 4):

*Expression* isn’t actually wrong, but it’s awfully general; when you’re talking about a word, it’s generally better to use the more precise term *word* (or sometimes *string*). For the example in your first paragraph I would write simply:

> Applying $f$ to $ab\in\text{lang}_1$ yields $abba\in\text{lang}_2$.

Your version is unnecessarily wordy. There’s no real need here for *function*, *word*, or *expression*: all are perfectly clear from the context.

Comment: I would either write "to the word $ab$" or "to $ab$", but "to the $ab$" looks awkward to me.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: To me as well. If I remember correctly, I originally wrote ‘to the word $ab$’ and then decided that ‘the word’ was unnecessary. Apparently I failed to erase both words.